# How do you implement continuous integration for .NET projects?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration

My company currently use CruiseControl.NET, which I find quite a pain on the neck to configure. What CI solution do you use?

Answer (score 3):

We use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html) which costs some coin, but is a huge step up from cruise control. It's simple, easy to configure and gives you tons of feedback on your builds. I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: I'm interested in TeamCity, but we've recently switched to SourceGear Vault for source control, which last time I checked, wasn't supported by TC. Any changes on that front?

Answer (score 3):

Try [CiFactory](http://code.google.com/p/ci-factory/)

Answer (score 2):

On my current project, we're using [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/), by Atlassian. I like it, and it has some pretty nice plugins available if you're using JIRA for bug tracking.

What has really helped us is that it is very flexible. We have a multiple Java and .NET apps, and Bamboo handles them all very well. It's not free, but if you have a complicated environment and build system, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I've heard Team Foundation has some features that let you have automated builds.

Comment: Yes, we do that, a bit tricky to get going, but works well  :)

Answer (score 1):

We used to use [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) but changed to use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html).

The automated build works really well and we would not want to develop without it now.

Answer (score 0):

We use CC or TeamCity by JetBrains (It's Free). I choose TeamCity over CC any day.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Zed Builds and Bugs](http://www.hericus.com/) here.  They have a community edition that is free for small setups, and a commercial version for larger projects/usage.

Nice features: there's no XML to edit to define your builds, and the whole thing is done using a very clean and consistent UI.